# Configure the delay afnetwork stores images

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

I want to be able control how much time the image is stored in the cache. This is how i download the image using afnetwork:

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:placeHolder];
```

I looked it up in the documentation, i didn't find anything interesting.

any clue?

EDIT: Additional question: is the cache stored in the disk? i guess so because images remain in the cache even after i close the application. but i am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking uses an [NSCache](http://nshipster.com/nscache/) instance, which will store more and more images in memory, until a memory warning is received, at which point it will remove some or all of the messages.  NSCache does not save to disk.

AFNetworking also uses [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which caches URL responses to disk based on (1) your NSURLRequest settings and (2) the cache headers sent by the HTTP server.  You can adjust the caching behavior in your app by setting the [NSURLRequestCachePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy), and on your server by setting the cache headers.

If that doesn't give you enough control, you may want to check out [SDURLCache](https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache), an open source NSURLCache alternative.

Comment: can you take a look at this http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/ ?
It says that the default behavior on ios 5 is to store to disk.

Also, i've taken a look at the links you gave me, but i can't find how to store cache permanently to disk. is it possible?